# Where is the Request class defined?

Tags: java, retrofit2

Baeldung has a nice [intro to Retrofit](https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit). I'm trying to use some of the ideas from the extended version of the GitHubServiceGenerator (under the "7. Logging" heading):

```
public class GitHubServiceGenerator {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder
      = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient
      = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging
      = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String token) {
        if (token != null) {
            httpClient.interceptors().clear();
            httpClient.addInterceptor( chain -> {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder builder1 = original.newBuilder()
                  .header("Authorization", token);
                Request request = builder1.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            });
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

In the code, these lines appear:

```
Request original = chain.request();
Request.Builder builder1 = original.newBuilder()
  .header("Authorization", token);
Request request = builder1.build();
```

I'm getting a compilation error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Request
```

Where can I find the `Request` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's [`okhttp3.Request`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.html).

You can find it by looking at where it is used, and then checking the API of that caller.  In this case, it is used in the `httpClient.addInterceptor()` method, and you can see in the snippet that you posted that `httpClient` is of class `OkHttpClient.Builder`.

A quick search shows that OkHttpClient.Builder comes from the `okhttp3` package [`okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html), which is the same package that defines the `Request` class that you were looking for.

That is also consistent with the "Overview" section of the link that you posted, which mentions "Square" and "Okhttp":

> Retrofit is a type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java – developed by Square (Dagger, Okhttp).

Comment: That was it. Much thanks. I'm pretty new to Java. My background is js, php, html, css. How did you know it was okhttp3?

Comment: I will add more info to the answer

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks!